# I am learning how to use volley but everytime i build my project it shows me this error. I couldn't find a solution which works for me

Tags: android, xml

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

here are the dependencies i added to my gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you google the error message.

Comment: You should also create a [mcve] which reproduces the error.

Comment: I believe your issue could be because you have duplicates/conflicts  I think you should remove `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` and also change the 2 remaining `compile`'s to `implementation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar` is deprecated and do not use 2 libraries for volley.
    Use only `**compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'**`
    you have conflicted with appcompat lib as well.
 Use this one

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

and remove

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

and add this in your `Build.gradle`

```
   android {
     defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
     }
   }
```

Comment: I am glad you found it useful.